# In javascript, how to user inputs save to a file to a local directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, file

I have decided to store files in my project locally. What I am hoping is when user click submit, the file will be save to a path, and I will make a Post request of the filename to a directory. How do you save files objects to a local directory?

```
export default class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.fileInput;
    this.handleFormSubmit = this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleFormSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    path = "../../images"
    // Save this.fileInput to path directory
  }


  render() {
    function FieldGroup({ id, label, help, ...props }) {
      return (
        <FormGroup controlId={id}>
          <ControlLabel>{label}</ControlLabel>
          <FormControl {...props} />
        </FormGroup>
      );
    }

    return (
      <Form>
        <FieldGroup
          id="formControlsText"
          type="text"
          label="title"
          placeholder="Enter text"
        />
        <FieldGroup
          id="formControlsFile"
          type="file"
          label="Image"
          help="Example block-level help text here."
          inputRef={ref => {this.fileInput = ref}}
        />
        <Button> Submit </Button>
      </Form>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You can't do this using client side js, you need to implement server side code to save files on server, although you can give option to download file or save data in localstorage at client side.

Comment: you can refer [this](https://dzone.com/articles/upload-files-or-images-to-server-using-nodejs) tutorial for the same

Answer (score -1):

You have to use either formidable or multer on your backend. Or, you can create a storage bucket online, and create a post request to store the image in the bucket.

Comment: You can also use expo's FileSystem API, if you use expo